# Add custom value in batch name like User Name as the batch Name

Tags: ocr, kofax

We have Invoice Processing project where Username wise folder is created and tiff file stored into those folder via FTP upload. We have configured Kofax import utility to import those tiff files and create the batch. Now We wanted to show the username into the batch name. 
Is there any way to add custom value into the batch name

Comment: Yes, end user has full control over the batch name (can even concatenate free text and field names to achieve desired result). Any person with a little bit of Kofax experience will know how to do this, otherwise refer to the Kofax site and download the developer guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the export utility in the batch class with a custom folder option set to generate the directory structure using a Kofax Capture Value field USERNAME as the picture shows...

[image]

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: @Fildor this is a simple batch configuration, and above screenshot perfectly navigates to the config parameters

Comment: Ok, obviously I am missing something. As I undetstand the question this is not what the op is looking for.